# How to cast a GLSurfaceView in Google Cast SDK v3?

Tags: android, chromecast, google-cast, android-cast-api

I would like my sender app to cast a GLSurfaceView to the receiver app in real time. This is possible in SDK v2 using the [Remote Display API](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/remote). Does SDK v3 have a similar feature, or must I render the contents of the GLSurfaceView to a MediaCodec corresponding to one of the [supported formats](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/media)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either use Cast SDK v2 (which supports the Remote Display APIs) or do something more complicated like what you suggested; Cast SDK v3 doesn't currently support the Remote Display APIs.